# Insert fails with FK constraint, can't find constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I think I'm just stupid so this won't be a difficult one to answer...but I have tried a few things and still stuck

I have to restore a table from our prod DB to a sandbox.  When I try to delete the rows in the destination table, I get the following err:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_XXX". The conflict occurred in database "Sandbox", table "dbo.YYYY", column 'ID'.
```

I have tried two separate scripts I found here to list the foreign keys and I get no results from those.  I also looked at all the tables listed in the error and I don't see a constraint listed.  If I can find the constraint I can drop it to insert the rows into the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you 'design' the table in SSMS, and then click on the 'relationships' button, you should see it.

You can also use the sp_fkeys procedure (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175090%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)